# Date formatting using JODA - Malformed at AM

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I am trying to format the following date

```
Thu, 15 Jan 2015, 9:56 AM
```

Using the following:

```
public String parse(String oldDate){
        final String OLD_FORMAT = "EEE, d MMM yyyy, HH:mm:ss zz";
        final String NEW_FORMAT = "yyyy/MM/dd";

        // August 12, 2010
        String oldDateString = oldDate;
        String newDateString;

        DateTimeFormatter formatterOld = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(OLD_FORMAT);
        DateTimeFormatter formatterNew = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(NEW_FORMAT);
        LocalDate localDate = formatterOld.parseLocalDate( oldDateString );
        return newDateString = formatterNew.print( localDate );
    }
```

I am getting a

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "Thu, 15 Jan 2015, 9:56 AM" is malformed at " AM"
```

How do I represent AM/PM properly in that date format? I tried using Z but get the same and changed to zz but invain. What is the correct representation for AM/PM?

I also checked with "hh:mm a" but that again does nto seem to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Z` and `z` are for TimeZones - you want `a` which is the format-code for *half-day*.

The formatting codes are describe in the [JavaDoc](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) for `org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat`

The code below works for me (running on a Java 8 JRE with Joda 2.6)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String format = "EEE, d MMM yyyy, HH:mm a";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(format);
    final LocalDate date = formatter.parseLocalDate("Thu, 15 Jan 2015, 9:56 AM");
    System.out.println(date);
}
```

Comment: I tried it with a and aa also but it throws the same error. Okay it was a problem with an extra space. Thanks this works :)